# For an assignment I need to make a christmas tree in C# and I need a little stem at the end but I don't know how

Tags: c#

So this is my code:

```
    
using System;

namespace kerstboom
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Enter Height //
            Console.WriteLine("Enter desired height:");
            // Read number entered //
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {
                var stars = new string('*', i);
                var spaces = new string(' ', n - i);
                Console.Write(spaces);
                Console.Write(stars);
                Console.Write("*");
                Console.Write(stars);
                Console.WriteLine(spaces);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it has to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDmF6.png

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Basically I'm looking for a fix of my code or just a whole new type of code as I'm pretty much stuck with this assignment.

Comment: Can you edit your answer in order to have a more readable code?

Comment: After finishing your loop you should also write a single star per line into the middle. WHere´s the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following after the loop

```
        Console.Write(new string(' ', n));
        Console.WriteLine("*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the total count of stars + spaces you have printed in the last line, as spaces and then just print a star:

```
using System;

namespace kerstboom
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Enter Height //
            Console.WriteLine("Enter desired height:");
            // Read number entered //
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            String stars = "";
            String spaces = "";

            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {
                stars = new string('*', i);
                spaces = new string(' ', n - i);
                Console.Write(spaces);
                Console.Write(stars);
                Console.Write("*");
                Console.Write(stars);
                Console.WriteLine(spaces);
            }
            
            spaces = new string(' ', stars.Length + spaces.Length);
            Console.Write(spaces);
            Console.Write('*');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the other logic, you'll realize that `stars.Length + spaces.Length` can be simplified.

Comment: You're right, I initially overlooked n. I do like how this reads though, even if it's not as concise.